# Pulling a specific branch from git

Tags: git, github

Im been trying around with git pulls. Managed to push a seperate branch now using: git push ---set-upstream origin (when in the branch). But im also looking for a way to pull this branch back.

I there a way to pull a separate branch? So instead of git pull git pull ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you always pull a specific branch, but you always fetch everything.

Pull will translate into fetch + merge or rebase (depending on your configuration).

Comment: Jeah, but lets say i want to pull 'feature1' branch in stead of 'master'

Comment: @user3706202 `git checkout feature1; git pull;`